# Rootkit I can not find.

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, dns, virus-removal, rootkit

I am running windows 7 ultimate. Chrome Browser. and advance system care. I have run every malware scanner I can find and all the rootkit scanners as well. Nothing seems to be able to find this thing.

The pop up a lot of places. But it seems they can not get in SSL accessed pages. Never on facebook or gmail or cpannel. I do beleive they are redirecting the DNS requests and using some other cache. I can clear my cache all day but the whole computer will still resolve an old IP. Chrome, IE, CMD>ping. All resolve the old IP. Until I restart the computer.

I could really use some help. I dont have a list of the software I tried but there were 7 or 8. All from a google search for rootkit removal.

Also, there are no host file entries.

Comment: `I do beleive they are redirecting the DNS requests and using some other cache.`   Use the command `ipconfig /flushdns`     `I can clear my cache all day but the whole computer will still resolve an old IP.`   Reboot.     `Chrome, IE, CMD>ping. All resolve the old IP. Until I restart the computer.`   See.     `I could really use some help.`   With what? You said that it resolves the correct IP after rebooting, so what’s the problem now?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you do not have a rootkit. perhaps some browser malware, but nothing so dramatic as a rootkit. if you do actually have a rootkit however, there is nothing to do but back up your content files (but no EXEs), and rebuild your PC. be sure remove and recreate the partition table of your hdd to ensure your MBR is overwritten.

Comment: Where this Causes the whole computer to resolve incorrect DNS entries I think its more than browser malware. And I am not going to reboot everytime I create a subdomain on my server or change an ip.